Merge rows in a specific sequence in SQL (Azure SQL)
Here is my sample data set:



ID
Timestamp
Duration
State




17
05.11.2024  00:00
0
Auto


16
04.11.2024  23:59
0
Auto


15
04.11.2024  23:58
1,47
Auto


14
04.11.2024  23:52
5,72
Manual


13
04.11.2024  23:52
0,13
Productive


12
04.11.2024  23:52
0,5
Error


11
04.11.2024  23:50
1,83
Auto


10
04.11.2024  23:50
0,08
Productive


9
04.11.2024  23:48
1,67
Auto


8
04.11.2024  23:48
0,12
Productive


7
04.11.2024  23:46
1,57
Auto


6
04.11.2024  23:46
0,17
Productive


5
04.11.2024  23:44
2,08
Auto


4
04.11.2024  23:44
0,1
Productive


3
04.11.2024  23:42
1,67
Auto


2
04.11.2024  23:42
0,13
Productive


1
04.11.2024  23:40
1,83
Auto



My target table should be this one:



ID
Timestamp
Duration
State




9
05.11.2024  00:00
0
Auto


8
04.11.2024  23:59
0
Auto


7
04.11.2024  23:58
1,47
Auto


6
04.11.2024  23:52
5,72
Manual


5
04.11.2024  23:52
0,13
Productive


4
04.11.2024  23:52
0,5
Error


3
04.11.2024  23:50
1,83
Auto


2
04.11.2024  23:42
7,59
Productive


1
04.11.2024  23:40
1,83
Auto



I would like all lines to be merged as soon as the status Productive and then alternately Auto - Productive appears. The duration is totalled in the process. How can I realise this with an SQL query? I've been thinking about this for days and unfortunately I can't find the right solution. I have already tried using CTE to create and group specific sequences. Unfortunately without success so far.

SSMS is just an IDE (like) application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

The data is stored in the Azure SQL DB

What you really need here is a [mre]. I would also suggest that using the name timestamp for a column is a bad idea. Not only is it a datatype in sql that has nothing to do with time of day it is also too ambiguous. Is that when the row was created, the last time it was edited or something else??

How are your combined duration values (7,59 and 1,83). calculated? They do not appear to be sums of the combined source values. Also, can the alternating sequence both start and end with 'Productive' such that the sequence Productive - Auto - Productive - Auto - Productive satisfies your criteria?

REVISED: The following is a completely revised answer using a gaps-and-islands approach. The original (but apparently incorrect) answer has been left in place further down.
After seeing p3consulting's answer, I now see that it appears that you wish to combine sequences of "Productive-Auto-Productive-...-Auto-Productive" consisting of 3 or more rows of alternating Productive/Auto state values and which start and end with "Productive".
This can be achieved using a gaps-and-islands approach, where the "islands" represent the rows to be combined and the "gaps" are carefully defined so as to be the transitions between islands.
As I understand the problem, a row may be combined with prior rows (and becomes a continuation of the same island) if:

It has a "Productive" state, and is preceded by rows having a "Productive-Auto" state sequence.
It has an "Auto" state, and is both preceded and followed by rows having "Productive" states.

Any other row, including rows having states other than "Productive" or "Auto", would be considered to be the start of a new "island" following a "gap".
Once the gaps are identified the islands are defined and numbered by calculating a running sum of the gap flags. It is then just a matter of combining rows in the same islands using GROUP BY and calculating the final results using appropriate aggregation functions. Note that an island might only consist of one row, which is not be combined with any other rows.
This approach can recognize and combine multiple matching sequenced within the same source data set.
WITH LagLead AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        LAG(State, 2) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Lag2,
        LAG(State, 1) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Lag1,
        LEAD(State, 1) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Lead1
    FROM Data
),
Gaps AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE
            WHEN State = 'Productive' AND Lag1 = 'Auto' AND Lag2 = 'Productive'
            THEN 0  -- productive-auto-PRODUCTIVE
            WHEN State = 'Auto' AND Lag1 = 'Productive' AND Lead1 = 'Productive'
            THEN 0  -- productive-AUTO-productive
            ELSE 1  -- Otherwise, this is a "gap" (the start of a new "island")
            END AS IsGap
    FROM LagLead
),
Islands AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(IsGap) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Island
    FROM Gaps
)
SELECT
    Island AS NewID,
    MIN(Timestamp) AS Timestamp,
    SUM(Duration) AS Duration,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 2 THEN 'Productive' ELSE MIN(State) END AS State,
    --MAX(CASE WHEN IsGap = 1 THEN State ELSE '' END) AS State2,
    COUNT(*) AS Rows
FROM Islands
GROUP BY Island
ORDER BY Island DESC

Results:



NewID
Timestamp
Duration
State
Rows




9
2024-11-05 00:00
0.00
Auto
1


8
2024-11-04 23:59
0.00
Auto
1


7
2024-11-04 23:58
1.47
Auto
1


6
2024-11-04 23:52
5.72
Manual
1


5
2024-11-04 23:52
0.13
Productive
1


4
2024-11-04 23:52
0.50
Error
1


3
2024-11-04 23:50
1.83
Auto
1


2
2024-11-04 23:42
7.59
Productive
9


1
2024-11-04 23:40
1.83
Auto
1



Intermediate results showing gaps and islands logic:



ID
Timestamp
Duration
Lag2
Lag1
State
Lead1
IsGap
Island




17
2024-11-05 00:00
0.00
Auto
Auto
Auto
null
1
9


16
2024-11-04 23:59
0.00
Manual
Auto
Auto
Auto
1
8


15
2024-11-04 23:58
1.47
Productive
Manual
Auto
Auto
1
7


14
2024-11-04 23:52
5.72
Error
Productive
Manual
Auto
1
6


13
2024-11-04 23:52
0.13
Auto
Error
Productive
Manual
1
5


12
2024-11-04 23:52
0.50
Productive
Auto
Error
Productive
1
4


11
2024-11-04 23:50
1.83
Auto
Productive
Auto
Error
1
3


10
2024-11-04 23:50
0.08
Productive
Auto
Productive
Auto
0
2


9
2024-11-04 23:48
1.67
Auto
Productive
Auto
Productive
0
2


8
2024-11-04 23:48
0.12
Productive
Auto
Productive
Auto
0
2


7
2024-11-04 23:46
1.57
Auto
Productive
Auto
Productive
0
2


6
2024-11-04 23:46
0.17
Productive
Auto
Productive
Auto
0
2


5
2024-11-04 23:44
2.08
Auto
Productive
Auto
Productive
0
2


4
2024-11-04 23:44
0.10
Productive
Auto
Productive
Auto
0
2


3
2024-11-04 23:42
1.67
Auto
Productive
Auto
Productive
0
2


2
2024-11-04 23:42
0.13
null
Auto
Productive
Auto
1
2


1
2024-11-04 23:40
1.83
null
null
Auto
Productive
1
1



See this db<>fiddle for a demo with some extra test data showing multiple combined row sequences.

Original Answer (Apparently incorrect, but left as a reference.)
If you look at the sequence from the reverse direction (ascending IDs), it appears that the main trick is to identify where the repeating alternating sequence Auto - Productive ends.
This can be done by counting the odd rows containing 'Auto' and the even rows containing 'Productive'. The sequence ends at the MAX(ID) where State = 'Productive' and both counts equal half the running total row count.
Once you have that, you can partition the data into two parts at that point, performing a grouping and aggregation on the first part and then UNION ALL that with the unmodified second part.
The final step is define new ID values using ROW_NUMBER().
WITH Counts AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS TCount, -- Total running count
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ID % 2 = 1 AND State = 'Auto' THEN 1 END)
            OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS ACount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ID % 2 = 0 AND State = 'Productive' THEN 1 END)
            OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS PCount
    FROM Data
),
Cutoff AS (
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
    FROM Counts
    WHERE State = 'Productive'
    AND ACount = TCount / 2
    AND PCount = TCount / 2
),
Combined AS (
    SELECT
        MIN(D.ID) AS OldID,
        MIN(Timestamp) AS Timestamp,
        SUM(Duration) AS Duration,
        State
    FROM Cutoff C
    JOIN Data D
        ON D.ID <= C.ID
    GROUP BY State

    UNION ALL

    SELECT D.ID AS OldId, Timestamp, Duration, State
    FROM Cutoff C
    JOIN Data D
        ON D.ID > C.ID
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OldID) AS ID,
    Timestamp, Duration, State
FROM Combined
ORDER BY ID DESC

If the source ID values are not guaranteed to be sequential starting at 1, you can add an extra CTE at the start to number the source data.
If you also allow your source data to start with 'Productive', you may need to also track odd rows containing 'Productive' and the even rows containing 'Auto' and check those alternate counts when selecting the cutoff.
Results:



ID
Timestamp
Duration
State




9
2024-11-05 00:00
0.00
Auto


8
2024-11-04 23:59
0.00
Auto


7
2024-11-04 23:58
1.47
Auto


6
2024-11-04 23:52
5.72
Manual


5
2024-11-04 23:52
0.13
Productive


4
2024-11-04 23:52
0.50
Error


3
2024-11-04 23:50
1.83
Auto


2
2024-11-04 23:42
0.60
Productive


1
2024-11-04 23:40
8.82
Auto



Note: The calculated combined duration values above (0.60 and 8.82) are different from your posted desired results (7,59 and 1,83). It is not clear to me how your values were calculated.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

A huge thank you! That's exactly what I needed. I have now changed the code so that the desired end table is filled. Thank you very much!

This version gives the same results as the required ones:
select min (d.id) as id, min(d.timestamp) as timestamp, max(state) as state,
    sum(duration) as duration 
from (
    select d.id, d.timestamp, d.duration, d.state, sum(diff) over (order by timestamp, id) as grp
    from (
        select d.*,
             case when 
                case when cls <> 'strt' then cls end = lag(cls) over(order by timestamp, id) then 0
                else 1
              end as diff
        from (
            select
                d.*,
                case state 
                    when 'Productive' then
                    case when 
                        lead(state, 1) over(order by timestamp, id) = 'Auto' 
                        then 'cycle' else 'strt' end
                    when 'Auto' then
                    case when 
                        lag(state) over(order by timestamp, id) = 'Productive' 
                        and lead(state) over(order by timestamp, id) = 'Productive'
                        then 'cycle' else 'strt' end
                    else 'strt'
                end as cls
            from data d 
        ) d
    ) d
) d
group by d.grp
;

https://dbfiddle.uk/8zFp7nSb

p3consulting - I had trouble following your logic at first, but after I revised my answer using gaps-and-islands approach, I realized that your answer had fundamentally similar logic, but was just structured differently and used different terms (diff = gap, grp = island). I do think that your diff logic can be simplified as shown in this db<>fiddle. I believe this also fixes a bug for when the range to be combined is followed by something other than "auto". Feel free to merge into your answer if you agree.

@TN, yes the simplification seems OK
